# Null check operator used on a null value - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api, dart-null-safety

I was trying to make a google drive app that lists files from the drive. but I got Null check operator used on a null value error. I got it what's happening. but I could not solve it.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
         body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('UPLOAD'),
            ),
            if (list != null)
              SizedBox(
                height: 300,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: list!.files?.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final title = list!.files![index].originalFilename;
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: Text(title!),
                      trailing: ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Download'),
                        onPressed: () {
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _listGoogleDriveFiles,
            child: Icon(Icons.photo),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run it upload text is showing and the error is showing below the text. So error must be due to list is null. but I just want to show the list only if it is not null.

What to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error means that you have used the `null` check operator (the exclamation mark) on something that instead happened to be `null` at runtime. So, looking at your code, it's not only the list that might be `null`, but also the other objects you marked with `!`.

The problem is somewhere here, unless I missed some `!` in your code:

```
itemCount: list!.files?.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final title = list!.files![index].originalFilename;
    return ListTile(
      leading: Text(title!),
      trailing: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Download'),
        onPressed: () {
          downloadGoogleDriveFile(
              filename: list!.files![index].originalFilename,
              id: list!.files![index].id);
        },
      ),
    );
},
```

To avoid encountering that error using `!`, you can explicitly check whether an object is `null`, something like:

```
if (list == null) {
   [...some error handling or a message with a warning]
} else {
   [your original code where you can use ! without fear of errors]
}
```

or you can assign a value to an object only in the case it is null, like this:

```
title??= ['Default title for when some loading failed or something'];
```

Comment: One important thing to notice here is that a null `itemCount` means infinite, not zero.

Comment: the problem was originalfilename. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that you are displaying the value when it is not done streaming. You need to finish streaming or building before you start displaying your data